# error: use of deleted function ‘std::thread::thread(const std::thread&)'

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread

The code bellow compiles and works as expected.
The structure (class) `A` derives from `std::thread` and expands with an `int` more.
The `main` code creates some threads and afterwards waits them to finish.

The problem is that while the code compiles without a destructor in struct `A`, when the destructor is **uncommented** ( `~A(){}` ) I get:

> error: use of deleted function ‘std::thread::thread(const std::thread&)'

and I have no idea on why.

Moreover I don't understand why the code works both with `push_back` and with `emplace_back` while according to what I understand it shouldn't work with `push_back`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

struct A : std::thread {
    int i;
    A(void f(const char*),const char* s,int i_) : std::thread{f,s},i{i_}{
        std::cout<<"A created"<<std::endl;
    }
    //~A(){} // uncomment to see error
};

void dosomething(const char* s){
    std::cout<<s<<std::endl;
}

int main(){
    std::vector<A> aa;
    aa.emplace_back(&dosomething,"hi people",3434);
    aa.push_back(A(&dosomething,"hi again people",777));
    aa.emplace_back(&dosomething,"hi again people",777);
    aa.push_back(A(&dosomething,"hi again people",777));

    for(auto& i:aa) i.join();
}
```

Comment: Which compiler version and options? I'm suspicious that it may be a compiler bug.

Comment: As to why it works with `push_back`, I believe your struct `A` is eligible for automatic generation of a move constructor, so `push_back` would be move-constructing the `A` in the vector from the temporary you pass in. (Note that there is a `push_back(value_type &&)` overload!)

Comment: -g;-O0;-Wall;-std=c++14;-pthread   both using g++ and clang++ and also using -std=c++11

Comment: compiles here: http://goo.gl/fyGEz8 and throws exception when run.

Comment: @RichardHodges I corrected adding the compile option -pthread and it compiles and executes as expected, but doesn't compile if the destructor is commented out

Comment: @chhowie yes but thread isn't moveable, so it shouldn't do it!

Comment: `std::thread` is moveable (and so is `A` until you add the destructor), but not copyable.

Comment: correction, sir: std::thread is certainly moveable.

Comment: Yes I was wrong, std::thread is moveable.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want the destructor, you can fix your code by adding

```
A(A &&) = default;
```

to reinstate the implicit move ctor.

---

Your first problem is that adding the user-defined destructor disables implicit generation of the *move* constructor.

The (misleading) error you see is the STL trying to fall back on copying types that can't be moved, and failing because `std::thread` is deliberately non-copyable.

See this [cppreference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor)'s section on the Implicitly-declared move constructor, and this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11255027/212858) for some related motivation.

The second source of confusion is that `push_back` has a move overload, so your original code was never copying in the first place, only moving. If you want to prove this, comment the dtor back out so it works again, and then try to `push_back` a const reference to an `A`. It will complain about the copy constructor, meaning the other `push_back` calls aren't using that.