# Visual Studio 2013 does not delete the copy constructor when a user-defined move constructor is provided

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-studio-2013

I appreciate the C++11 standard dictates:

> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy
>   constructor, one is declared implicitly. **If the class definition
>   declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the
>   implicitly declared copy constructor is defined as deleted**; otherwise,
>   it is defined as defaulted.

(actually copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11255089))

The following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct C
{
    int x = 1;

    C()
    {
    }

    C(C&&)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    const C c;
    C c2(c);

    std::cout << c.x << " " << c2.x << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

does not compile on `gcc 4.9.0`, but compiles just fine on Visual Studio 2013 (`Compiler Version 18.00.21005.1 for x86`). Is this yet another Visual Studio violation of the standard, or am I doing something wrong this time? If this is a violation of the standard, is there a tracking bug or any source where this behaviour is documented?

Comment: Can you post the compilation error message(s) ? Would be useful...

Comment: @floppy12 : http://ideone.com/yhqPBb That's gcc 4.9.2 in c++14 mode. Your gcc will probably do the same. Anyway it's not the presence of an error with gcc the problem, but its absence with VS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong, and your interpretation of the standard is correct. Visual C++ 2013 indeed does not implement these rules properly.

A relevant bug report is here:

[Default copy constructor is generated even when a custom move constructor is defined [c++11]](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/995876/default-copy-constructor-is-generated-even-when-a-custom-move-constructor-is-defined-c-11)

It's marked as `Won't Fix` and the comment from the development team is:

> Visual Studio 2013 indeed does not fully implement the C++11 rules
>   governing special member functions and move operations. We will
>   include a fix for this bug in the next major release of Visual Studio.

The good news is that things seem to be working properly in Visual C++ 2015 RC. I've just verified that your code triggers both compiler and IntelliSense errors. The compiler diagnostic is:

```
error C2280: 'C::C(const C &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

(From what I've tested during the past few months, MSVC14 is shaping up as a pretty good C++ compiler - lots of standard compliance issues have been fixed.)

Comment: That's indeed good news *for the future*, but for the present it's a hell of a problem. If you have to break the standard, I am fine if you do it by not providing the functionality X or Y, but if you provide half of it, you can put entire projects in severe jeopardy. A copy happening my mistake could be a disaster.

Comment: @gd1 Yeah, I feel your pain. However, in places where preventing copies is so important that it could make or break the project, I'd say it's a good idea to explicitly `= delete` the copy constructor (and probably the copy assignment operator too) anyway. That's what I'm doing so far in Visual C++ 2013, and this part works fine.