# Why is the copy assignment operator implicitly defined?

Tags: c++, c++11

Default Constructor, Copy Constructor and Destructor are very important and I understand why C++ implicitly defined them. Just think about function arguments that should be copied, local variables that should be destructed and objects that should be construct-able even if you don't say how to construct.

But why do we need the copy assignment operator **implicitly defined**? Is it really a must to be able to do `a = b`? It is not game changing, right? Any strong reason I don't know?

Comment: Well isn't natural to want to do `foo = bar;`?

Comment: Why would it make sense for something that is copyable not to be copy assignable by default?

Comment: The question is as unclear as waters of Hudson in NY Harbor. What do you mean by game changing? Nothing is game changing, people were living in caves 70000 years ago, and it didn't differ much from how we live now.

Comment: @SergeyA, while you are trying to make a joke here, people answer to my question :) No offense, please.

Comment: Well your last edit completely invalidated my looong answer.

Comment: no problem. but question is more or less opinion based - "because we can" or "because normally we can not invoke destructor manually"

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11255258/576911

Comment: There is actually an interesting point to this, which is _should this be the case_? It ties in to the question of whether a language should be designed to promote mutability of objects or not. Personally I'd like to see objects `const` by default, and this question is at the heart of whether or not that would ever be a good idea. _Do_ we always want to be able to assign to things by default? (Ironically, if objects were `const` by default then we probably _would_ want implicit assignment operators, because the only time they could be used is when the object were deliberately marked `mutable`.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ... why do we need the copy assignment operator?

Simply, to support assignment semantics. These are not the same as copy construction semantics.

```
Foo f1;
Foo f2(f1); // copy...
Foo f3;
f3 = f1; // assignment...
```

They are similar, and often implemented in terms of one another, but not the same.

***Why would they all be implicitly defined?***

To support and mimic the C-style value semantics. **So that user defined types can support the same semantics as the built in types.**

*Side note*; IIRC, there has been [some deprecation of rules here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11255258/3747990) with the onset of move semantics...

Comment: Would upvote, if not for my strong belief that the question is unclear, useless and should be closed.

Comment: @SergeyA. At your discretion. Given the edit, I think he cleared it up... except maybe the "game changer"...

Comment: So there are two reasons 1. to mimic C-style syntax and also for UDT to support the same semantics as for built-in ones.

Comment: @Narek. The original motivation has been refined over the years, but there was a strong desire to allow UDT to mimic built in type, this was important to support a general purpose language. Our understanding of the consequences of this has evolved over the years leading to the "rule of three", "rule of five" and "the rule of zero". Allied to this is the evolution of the formal rules regarding these special members as well - but none of these take away, in fact they add to, the motivation to support value semantics. As an aside, this is also intimately tied to the RAII mechanisms in C++.

Comment: @Narek, "The Design and Evolution of C++" makes for a good read.

Answer (score 4):

I believe it comes from one of the properties/capabilities of C++ which is being able to compile the native C code.

In C you are able to assign one `struct` variable to another e.g.

```
typedef struct foo_s
{
    int field1;
    int field2;
} foo_t;

int main ()
{
    foo_t a, b;

    a.field1 = 1;
    a.field2 = 2;

    b = a;

    return 0;
}
```

So you should be able to compile this code as C++ thus you **must have a default assignment operator**.

Comment: Alex, I think this is the answer of my question. So, strictly saying, this is just for backward compatibility?

Comment: Why do you say you didn't understand the question? Looks right to me.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The original question was about assignment operator in general, not only the default one. But now I see that the question has been edited...

Answer (score 1):

If you copy-construct an object, you are able to set const members. Imagine you already have an object and then want to do an assignment. This would violate the constness of the members.

To clarify this a bit - because this short text seemed to be not sufficient for the most people - here some code:

```
struct C {

  const int i;
  C(int i) :i(i) {};
};

int main(void) {

  C a(5), b(7);

  a = b; // compiler error
  C c(a);  // no error

  return 0;
}
```

So you **need** the assignment operator, because it has different semantics.

It is implicitly defined - if possible - because assignment should be defined by default whenever it is possible. Note, that in most cases your assignment operator is actually *not* implicitly defined. The above code is just one example, but there are many other cases: if you have a user declared move constructor for instance, then the copy assignment operator is *not* implicitly defined.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have having a hard time understanding why this is an answer.  The OP is asking why the copy assignment operator is implicitly created for us.

Comment: @NathanOliver the OP also asked "why we need copy assignment operator" - and this is the answer.

Comment: Okay he ask both but this still doesn't answer *why we need copy assignment operator*

Comment: This doesn't even answer "why we need copy assignment operator".

Comment: @juanchopanza yes it does, but maybe not clear enough. I added some code, that shows, why you need the distinction between copy ctor and copy assignment.

Comment: @UniversE It may do so now, but it most certainly didn't before. You didn't just add some code. You actually tried to answer the question.