# Why is the compiler trying to copy instead of moving the return value?

Tags: c++, function, constructor, move, rvalue-reference

My code looks like

```
// definition of class 'Foo'
class Foo
{
  private:
    vector<Bar> v;
  public:
    ...
    Foo(Foo&&) = default; // move constructor
};

// definition of function 'f'
Foo f()
{
  Foo x;
  DoStuff(x);
  return x;
}

// Somewhere in main
result = f(); // I am aiming to move 'x' to 'result'
```

When I try to compile I receive

```
EAL_1.6.cpp:314:13: error: object of type 'Foo' cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted
        x = f(x);
            ^
EAL_1.6.cpp:232:5: note: copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted because 'Foo' has a user-declared move constructor
    Foo(Foo&&) = default;
    ^
```

I was tempted to try

```
return move(x);
```

but it does not appear to be a clever solution according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473753/c11-return-value-optimization-or-move). I understand that the cop constructor is deleted when defining a move constructor (as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255027/why-user-defined-move-constructor-disables-the-implicit-copy-constructor)) but I don't understand how to tell the compiler that I would like 'x' to be moved to 'result'.

Comment: The error and the code are showing two completely different things. Also what is `Bar`?

Comment: Do you have `Foo& operator=(Foo&&)=default;`? Because it will not be generated implicitly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This:

```
result = f(); // I am aiming to move 'x' to 'result'
```

isn't an attempt at move *construction*, it's an attempt at move *assignment*. And, as the compiler is telling you:

> object of type `Foo` cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted

The copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted (and the move assignment operator is simply absent entirely) because you added the move constructor. Presumably, if your type is move constructible, it's also move assignable. So just add:

```
Foo& operator=(Foo&& ) = default;
```

Comment: @0x499602D2 Thanks!