# Why is the move constructor defined and the assignment operator implicitly deleted?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, g++

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(Foo&&) = default;
};

int main()
{
    Foo a, b;
    a = b;
   // ^ 

   return 0;
}
```

error: use of deleted function 'Foo& Foo::operator=(const Foo&)'

in g++4.6 -std=c++0x  it's ok.
but, in g++6.2 -std=c++11 it's error.
why?

Comment: Read further : "*note: ‘constexpr Foo& Foo::operator=(const Foo&)’ is implicitly declared as deleted because ‘Foo’ declares a move constructor or move assignment operator*". And that is because of the standard says so : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255027/why-user-defined-move-constructor-disables-the-implicit-copy-constructor

Answer (score 10):

The answer is because the C++ standard says so:

> [class.copy]
>
> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy
>   constructor, one is declared implicitly. If the class definition
>   declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the
>   implicitly declared copy constructor is defined as deleted; otherwise,
>   it is defined as defaulted (8.4).

You can always declare a default copy constructor, in your case:

```
 Foo(const Foo&) = default;
```

Answer (score 4):

Sam has explained why GCC 6.2's behaviour is correct.

GCC 4.6's behaviour is simply due to incomplete C++11 support in that version (as evidenced by the "experimental" C++0x switch); C++11 was not fully supported until 4.8.